# Finding a volume integral in an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian

I am trying to find the volume integral of $\rho=\rho_{0}\left(\frac{R^{2}-r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)$ inside an ellipsoid given by
$\frac{x^{2}}{(3 R)^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{(4 R)^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{(5 R)^{2}}=1$

I've tried using jacobian to move from an ellipsoid to an unit ball by these mapping relationships

> $x=3 R u$,
> $y=4 R v$,
> $z=5 R w$

But the resulting integral is still heavy

$\int\rho_0\left(1-\left(9 u^{2}+16 w^{2}+25 w^{2}\right)\right) 60 dudvdw$

Does anyone have any insight to a more elegant way.

Thank you

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no convenient way to deal with a problem like this. No matter what transformation you develop, you either push the problem to the boundary (have weird integration bounds) or to the integrand (have a weird function to integrate). I would say now that you have the integral over the unit ball, transform into spherical coordinates and just deal with the headache there. Good luck!

Comment: Just looking in spherical is scary

Comment: btw, here's [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3276326/568204) I wrote a while back where I address similar issues of integrating low degree polynomials over the unit ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting integral in this case is actually very simple due to symmetry:
\begin{align}
\int_Bu^2\,dV = \int_Bv^2\,dV = \int_Bw^2\,dV=\frac{1}{3}\int_B(u^2+v^2+w^2)\,dV = \frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 r^2\,4\pi r^2\,dr =\frac{4\pi}{15}.
\end{align}

This symmetry should be intuitive enough. Otherwise use the change of variables theorem to permute $(u,v,w)$ and the fact that the unit ball remains invariant under this change of coordinates, and that the absolute value of the determinant of this is $1$ if you want a really rigorous proof.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your last integral is not that heavy.

The constant $1$ yields the volume of the unit sphere. Then using spherical coordinates, the integral of $w^2$ is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 r^2\cos^2\phi\,r^2\sin\phi\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta=2\pi\frac23\frac15.$$

By symmetry, the integrals of $u^2$ and $v^2$ are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much.